# Previous and current selected options in Prototype

Tags: html-select, prototypejs

How can I get the previously selected option from a `<select>` in prototype so I can "rollback" the selection should anything fail in the script ?

Comment: By keeping track of the previously selected value in a separate variable, for example?

Comment: Sure, but being prototype a robust js solution I wonder if there's some built-in funcionality for such value.

Comment: @xain I'd consider this to be more of 'custom component' functionality. Prototype adds a lot of features that make building components like this fairly painless (classes, event stuff, dom stuff), but nothing like that is out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly with prototype, but here is a class to handle "rollbackable" selects:

```
var UndoableSelect = Class.create({
    _$select: null,
    _selectedValue : null,
    _lastSelectedValue: null,
    initialize: function(elementOrId)
    {
        this._$select = $(elementOrId);
        this._lastSelectedIndex = this._$select.selectedIndex;
        this._selectedIndex = this._lastSelectedIndex;
        this._$select.observe('change', this._changeHandler.bind(this));
    },
    undoLastSelection: function()
    {
        this._$select.selectedIndex = this._lastSlectedIndex;
        this._selectedIndex = this._lastSelectedIndex;
    },
    _changeHandler: function(event)
    {
        this._lastSelectedIndex = this._selectedIndex;
        this._selectedIndex = this._$select.selectIndex;
    }
});
```

That you can use like that:

```
// this one line under has to be called only once per page load (where there is the select of course):
var theSelect = new UndoableSelect('id_of_the_select');
$('id_of_the_select').observe('change', function(event)
{
    // your code, if you need to rollback, do this:
    theSelect.undoSelection();
});
```

Sorry not so much explanation but I don't have much time now. I just wrote the code without testing so if any problem let me know and I'll be back on it with more time to fix it ;-)